# xslt transform xml to xml how to get attibutes of an entity?

Tags: xslt

I want to transform an xml to naother xml, with xstl
I have an entity `<AAA id="e1" ts=" bb">`
How can i get this entity with the attributes in my new xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<xsl:copy-of>` element can be used to accomplish what you're getting after.

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy-of select="AAA" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is run against the following sample XML:**

```
<t>
  <AAA id="e1" ts=" bb" />
</t>
```

**...the wanted result is produced:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AAA id="e1" ts=" bb" />
```